# Get a ClassCastException when Spring upload file filter by Apache Shiro

Tags: spring, security, web, upload, shiro

I used Apache Shiro for AA of a Web project, Spring is also used. When upload file, will get following exception, I can not find relevant case from google. Anybody have seen this before?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
com.weardex.web.filter.auth.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:62)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using grails (same difference).  I was missing the enctype in the form (enctype="multipart/form-data") and it worked again:

Based on this answer [groovy upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753905/groovy-upload-file) I realized that my encompassing form was over-riding the internal form.